# C++ Menu stuck in infinite if user enters invalid integer

Tags: c++, menu, user-input, infinite-loop

I have a simple C++ menu with selectable menu options. If the user types anything other than a valid `int`, such as a `char` or `double`, the program will go into an infinite loop. My code is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int selection;
    do  {
        cout << "1) Update inventory" << endl;
        cout << "2) Sell items" << endl;
        cout << "3) List inventory" << endl;
        cout << "4) Quit" << endl;

        cout << "Please select an option: ";
        cin >> selection;
    }
    while (selection != 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Why do invalid responses cause an infinite loop and how can it be prevented?

Comment: you want to check the validity of the stream, like `if (!cin) { /*handle error*/ }`. See also [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score -1):

Before the

```
cin >> selection;
```

Place these two lines:

```
cin.clear ();
cin.ignore ();
```

This will clear the buffer and allow input to be taken.

Comment: This is not what he was asking.  He is asking about invalid input, such as a character being entered instead of a number

Comment: I realize. This will solve the problem. But @jaggedSpire is right.